# \paragraph{} sectioning with eledmac/eledpar

Tags: sectioning, eledmac, eledpar

Maybe just a short question: In a layout with parallel pages using eledpar and eledmac I try to use the \paragraph sectioning command (and KOMA-Script), which causes the layout going off perfect sync.

Is there a equivalent to the \paragraph{}-command for eledmac/eledpar, or is it better to build something like: `\noindent\textbf{1.}\hspace{0.7em} text…` manually?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Here's an MWE. The first two paragraphs go out of sync:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,BCOR=12mm,DIV=14]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman, polutonikogreek, latin]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{eledmac}
\usepackage{eledpar}


\begin{document}
\begin{pages}
\begin{Leftside}
\selectlanguage{latin}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
\eledchapter*{Titel}
\pend\pstart
\eledsection*{Section}
\pend\pstart
\paragraph{bla} phantomtext phantomtextphantomtext phantomtext phantomtext phantomtext
\pend\pstart\itshape
\paragraph{2.} phantomtext2 phantomtext2 phantomtext2 phantomtext2 phantomtext2 phantomtext2
\pend\pstart\itshape
\paragraph{3.} phantomtext3 phantomtext3 phantomtext3 phantomtext3 phantomtext3 phantomtext3 phantomtext3.
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{Leftside}
%ENDE LINKE SEITE


%BEGINN RECHTE SEITE
\begin{Rightside}
\selectlanguage{ngerman}
\beginnumberingR
\pstart
\eledchapter*{Titel}
\pend\pstart
\eledsection*{Section}
\pend\pstart
\paragraph{bla} phantomtext phantomtextphantomtext phantomtext phantomtext phantomtext phantomtext
\pend\pstart\itshape
\paragraph{2. bla} phantomtext2 phantomtext2 phantomtext2 phantomtext2 phantomtext2 phantomtext2
\pend\pstart\itshape
\paragraph{3.} phantomtext3 phantomtext3 phantomtext3 phantomtext3 phantomtext3.
\pend
\endnumberingR
\end{Rightside}
\end{pages}
\Pages
\end{document}
```

Comment: What's going in the `\paragraph` or `\textbf`?  Are you counting something, or might it be a combination or text and numbers?

Comment: Please edit your question and add there a little complete document illustrating the problem mentioned.

Comment: I'm not counting anything but would like to have a graphical sectioning, with text going on in the same line. An MWE is coming.

Comment: They line up for me: in `Leftside`, there is a blank line in the output between paragraphs "bla." and "2." such that all three paragraphs start at the same place with respect to the corresponding paragraph on the "`Rightside`" page.

Comment: Oh good to know. For me there no blank line between "bla." and "2." on the Leftside. This where the sync doesn't work. But I remember that the problem didn't exist with earlier version of eledmac/eledpar. Which version are you using, jon? I'm running version 1.24.2 for eledmac and 1.17.0 of eledpar.

Comment: with book, it's working. with scrbook, there is problem of sync (even without your \eledsection, which are not need for your MWE). I think your problem is with scrbook. Plese open an github issue, even if I can't assure to look for it quickly.

Comment: ps : you should not use \beginnumberingR and \endnumberingR. That is internal command automatically call when you use \beginnnumbering in a right side. I can't assure that the \beginnumberingR will be kept in the futur of eledpar.

Comment: Thanks Maïeul! I've opened a github issue (without the unnecessary sections). But it's for now good to know that it has to do with scrbook.