# reledmac/reledpar: Using \paragraph together with scrbook

Tags: koma-script, reledmac, reledpar

## General Problem

I want to use the `\paragraph` command within the optional argument of the `\pstart` command. In my MWE it works perfectly for `\chapter` and friends.

But it doesn't work for `\paragraph`.

## MWE (Code)

```
\documentclass[]{scrbook}

\usepackage[]{reledmac}

\usepackage[]{reledpar}
% reledpar configuration
\setlength{\columnrulewidth}{0.4pt}

% level of section numbering
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}

\begin{document}

\begin{pairs}
    \begin{Leftside}
        \beginnumbering
            \pstart[\chapter{Chapter Test (Language A)}]
            Text in language A.
            \pend 
        \endnumbering           
    \end{Leftside}
    %
    \begin{Rightside}
        \beginnumbering
            \pstart[\chapter{Chapter Test (Language B)}]
            Text in language B.
            \pend 
        \endnumbering   
    \end{Rightside}
\end{pairs}
\Columns

\begin{pairs}
    \begin{Leftside}
        \beginnumbering
            \pstart[\paragraph{Paragraph Test (Language A)}]
            Text in language A.
            \pend 
        \endnumbering           
    \end{Leftside}
    %
    \begin{Rightside}
        \beginnumbering
            \pstart[\paragraph{Paragraph Test (Language B)}]
            Text in language B.
            \pend 
        \endnumbering   
    \end{Rightside}
\end{pairs}
\Columns

\end{document}
```

## MWE (Output)

[image]

## Related Question(s)

- [\paragraph{} sectioning with eledmac/eledpar](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/253700/paragraph-sectioning-with-eledmac-eledpar)

Comment: `\paragraph`  inside reledmac is not integrated. I suggest you to create a commande which similate it.

Comment: @Maïeul Thanks a lot. Do you know if this is documented somewhere? Is it hard to also integrate it?

Comment: no, there is no documentation about it. But for example you could do something like this `\newcommand{\myparagraph}[1]{\textbf{#1}\hspace{1em}}`

Comment: @Maïeul The problem is that I need a number for the paragraph...

Comment: not a problem. add just `\refstepcounter{paragraph}\thecounter`

Comment: @Maïeul Ok. Perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comment of [Maïeul](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/7712) states there is **no solution** (yet) since the `reledmac` package does not support `paragraph` and beyond.

Comment: you could open an issue of course, but as you can see I have a lot of todo list on reledmac, and also a phd thesis to finish.

Comment: @Maïeul It's ok - I just wanted to document the result of the discussion so that others can easily find it in Google. I wish you luck/success with your thesis.